# Hairline gaps between shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustration

I'm new to Illustrator and have created some icons. When I export to svg, I get thin white lines between shapes. There is no gap when I'm using Illustrator.

[image]

I've taken a look on the web with the main solution being place the same colour behind the shape to hide the gap.

These seems quite clunky, is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3):

This is usually caused by Illustrator's at-times clunky anti-aliasing. The reason that the main solution you're seeing is to put a shape behind it or extend some of the shapes behind each other is because it's the pretty much the only way to correct it if the math is perfect.