# Gaps between shapes when exporting from illustrator to photoshop

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, vector, export, shapes

I often have .ai files that need to be exported to .psd but with paths retained. To retain all vectors I follow [this tutorial](http://theiconmaster.com/2012/02/exporting-illustrator-paths-to-photoshop-shape-layers/).  All works as fine, expect for the fact that I often end up having small hairline gaps between different shapes, the same shapes stick perfectly to each other in Illustrator or even an exported PNG.

Here's what it looks like as a PNG / AI

[image]

And this is what I get in Photoshop

[image]

Here's a few questions I came across on SE

[Space between 2 paths in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/47342/space-between-2-paths-in-illustrator)

[Fix gap between path and shapes in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55816/fix-gap-between-path-and-shapes-in-illustrator)

[Hairline gaps between shapes](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58521/hairline-gaps-between-shapes)

There are a few more that I went through, but can't find them now. In any case, they all had the same explanation and solution suggested.

1. This is caused due to issues with Anti-Aliasing in Illustrator
2. Solution 1 : Keep an object behind the area where the line shows up and give this object a favourable solid fill color
3. Solution 2 : Use Illustrator's path offset feature to "grow" all shapes my  a small unnoticeable amount so the shapes then appear to be contact

I can't use the first solution as these AI files are normally icons with no specific background, would be tedious to fill the gaps manually

The second solution is helpful, but more of something I would try if all else fails. This is because :

1. The solution I followed to retain vectors needs all shapes to be converted to compound shapes before exporting. However, because of this, I tend to have a lot of compound shapes for each separate element. To make things worse, any group in AI get's exported as a rasterized layer. So I need to keep a rather long list of compound shapes.
2. When using the offset feature, I noticed that it adds a slightly larger new path below the selected shape, which means I'll have even more elements to handle now. This doesn't seem like a problem with simple designs, however when it comes to larger complex artworks things get quite messy.

Are there any other ways of solving this problem.

EDIT :

Here's the [AI file](http://projectilepixels.com/docs/Gear.ai)

Comment: can you attach the ai file

Comment: @atek I've added a download link to the file

Answer (score 1):

Get your wheel merged into a single shape by using the `Pathfinder > Unite` tool. This joins all the pieces into a single shape with no intersection areas, etc. This is also good to prevent the pieces from moving accidentally and you always get the shape *locked* in this final form.

[image]
Or, since you wish to avoid compound shapes, you could increase the size of the circle shape a bit, so the intersection area gets overlapped. Even a very slight increase of the circle size will fix this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @Lucian, however I was looking for something more generic, the gear icon was just an example. Also all paths would need to be separate in PSD to maintain high level of editability.

Answer (score 1):

For the Gear
Select all (ctrl+A) The shfit click the circle and deselect the circle only
and just drag and see only the teeth of the gear are selected. In the Window > pathfinder (shift+ctrl+f9). Click on the **unite**

[image]

Now select all (ctrl+A) again go to window > pathfinder (shift+ctrl+f9) and click **unite** everything will merge. And after u export to psd u will get the fill effect
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another option if you are using the same colour for all shapes (such as icons) is to just add a small stroke as a layer effect.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Very unintuitively, if you duplicate the Photoshop layer the transparent gaps disappear[image].