# How to remove line of "join" vector shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, export, png

I am new to Illustrator and am suffering when trying to export 2 unified vectors to PNG file.

The exported image ends up with the "trace" on union of two objects.

Is there any way to solve this "problem"?

Exported result (.png):

[image]

On Illustrator file:

[image: Vector's Joined]

No lines here:

[image: Joined on Illustrator (no lines here)]
[image: Separated]

Export Settings:

[image: Export Settings]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hairline gaps between shapes](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58521/hairline-gaps-between-shapes)

Answer (score 3):

**It's because of limited pixel density in exported png**

=> when you make anything in illustrator it means you've made vector asset and vector is based on points which is Density independent so no matter how long or small you zoom it. it'll be always same clear as before and no pixelation will be happen.

=> now come to the PNG (take photoshop) whenever you export your asset to something like png and jpg. your vector doesnt remain same and it's characteristic get converted from points to pixel so now all your artwork will be converted to pixel(smallest possible square of color) and will get assigned to some DPI ( mostly 72).

=> now the reason i explained both term is because when you convert your vector to raster(PNG and JPG etc) it only do transformation to pixel level and when your artwork contains gap like 0.24545 pixels then it renders 1 blank pixel because subpixel transformation isn't possible in raster images. look down below image to understand more.

==> It seems like no gap at all in illustrator (there is very slight gap) but hardly visible on 6400% zoom)

[image]

==> but when it exported in pixels it shows 1 pixel transparent line. so to avoid it you have to merge shapes as much as possible. i use Shapebuilder tool (<kbd>Shift+M</kbd>) and avoid using cross lines if you don't wanna merge. as long as there is straight line gaps (horizontal and vertical ) there shouldn't be any problem.

[image]

Hope this helps!

**TLDR: Just use as many as merged shapes. use any methods to merge shapes and it'll turn out in good result.**

Comment: It is actually a bug, it is a deep entrenched bug. But a bug nonetheless. It even has a name the white line you see is a conflation artifact, because it conflates coverage with alpha blending. But that should not be done! Common to see, even more common in classrooms across the world. It is as if computer scientist all around the world have decided to teach people to make this bug on purpose, kind of bug. There is no need for the bug to exist.

Comment: @joojaa bugs everwhere :D but i kinda ate that bug by fork lol. I only hate this when i download premade vector and it have curvy lines everywhere and results can't be patched anymore XD

Comment: @joojaa it's not just a bug in Illustrator, the same problem occurs in other vector software such as Inkscape, and CorelDraw.

Comment: @BillyKerr Yeah i know its why i said that its as if computrer scientist conspire to make the same flaw everywhere. But the thing is, that the GPU viewport of illustrator does it much better than any of the export modes so it can be surprising that this is a problem in the export. (Mainly because 3d graphics programmers knew about this issue form day one, and worked really really hard to avoid it. Thus GPU programmers know this). But it does not have to occur, if you use the legacy save for web and put the art optimized AA on it does not show up

Comment: Hey @DesignPhoenix! Thanks for the answer! But, how I can join two vector with Shape Builder Tool?

Comment: @Igor just select two colliding shapes. in your case light green lines . and press <kbd>Shift+M</kbd> then drag your one shape into another. it quite very easy :D https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJaeqJgIDO4 watch this video XD

Comment: @DesignPhoenix We try this before but it does not work in our scenario. We would like to know if there is any other way to do this, please see: https://imgur.com/a/577G509 (This removes the shapes).

Comment: @Igor OOps! it's not shape builder mistake. basically upon merging the shape builder tool with inherit active foreground color of illustrator so that means when you will merge shape the new shape will have color of your active foreground so to avoid it only select the shapes which you want to merge. in your chase. select only two green lines and upon merging it the filler color will also green :D

Comment: @Design Phoenix All right! Soon we will try what you said, and we will return in comments! Thank you again :)

Comment: @Design Phoenix It's works like a boss! Note: Placing a vector behind junction also helps solve the problem when exporting.

Comment: Glad it helped solving your issue and more of that i hope you learned logic behind the cause :) please don't forget to mark answer as accepted if you are satisfied with answer :D